# Ignore all nested subdirectories in .tfignore

Tags: .net, visual-studio, tfs, version-control

I have a folder structure like so:

```
-root
 -Proj1
    -Addedthings
       -Tables
          TableFiles
  -Proj2 
    -Addedthings
      -Tables
        TableFiles
   -Proj3
     TableFiles
   .tfignore
```

In this case I want to exclude all files inside of any of the AddedThings/Tables/ directories.

I have tried doing 
AddedThings/Tables

and

/AddedThings/Tables

And I have had no luck. Can someone please assist.

Answer (score 2):

[`.tfignore`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/repos/tfvc/add-files-server?view=vsts#customize-which-files-are-ignored-by-version-control) file will ignore the given pattern in *all* subdirectories .  And it will ignore files *or* folders with the given name.  For folders, it will apply recursively.

As a result, a `.tfignore` with:

```
Tables
```

This will ignore any folder named `Tables` in your filesystem hierarchy, and it will ignore them recursively.

For those Tables folder which is not under  `Addedthings/Tables`  you can **create .tfignore files in sub-folders to override the effects of a .tfignore file in a parent folder.**

***Note:***

1. A filespec is recursive unless prefixed by the `\` character.
2. This `.tfignore` file will not affect with those files already in source control. You need to remove them from source control first. Also make sure your .tfignore files have checked in source control.

Comment: Hmm so it cannot be a path with multiple parts?

Comment: Yes, it can. But if you don't specify a path the answer applies. Also, see the note if your file/folder is in the folder where `.tfignore` resides.